# Discontinuous borders in table

Tags: tables

I currently use the following code to generate a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newenvironment{kiquotes}{
    \noindent \begin{tabular}{|Y{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr 0.65\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
    \hline\addlinespace[0.3cm]
}{
    \addlinespace[0.3cm]\hline \end{tabular}\\[0.1cm]
    \par
}

\newcommand{\kiquote}[2]{#1: & \guillemotright{}#2\guillemotleft{} \\ }

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{kiquotes} \kiquote{Someone}{Said something} \end{kiquotes}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

However, the resulting table lacks borders where `\addlinespace` is added. How can I prevent this from happening such that I have a continuous border?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to load the `makecell` package and use `\setcellgapes{0.3cm}`; the dimension `0.3cm` is your choice. Before the tabular, you have to activate this setting by issuing the `\makegapedcells` command. If you want to undo the last command, issue the inverse `\nomakegapedcells` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{aeguill}    
\usepackage{makecell}  % <====
\setcellgapes{0.3cm}   % <====

\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newenvironment{kiquotes}{\makegapedcells   % <====
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{|Y{\dimexpr0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr0.65\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
    \hline
}{
    \hline \end{tabular}\\
    \par
}

\newcommand{\kiquote}[2]{#1: & \guillemotright{}#2\guillemotleft{} \\ }

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{kiquotes} \kiquote{Someone}{Said something} \end{kiquotes}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Note:**

A totally different idea that might fit your needs is to use a `tcolorbox` instead of `tabular`s, it has many flexible settings and can break across page borders.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the content inside an `\fbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\kiquote}[2]{{%
  \noindent
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}% Locally adjust \fboxsep (change to suit your needs)
  \fbox{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr.35\linewidth-\fboxrule-\fboxsep][l]{#1:}%
    \makebox[\dimexpr.65\linewidth-\fboxrule-\fboxsep][l]{\guillemotright #2\guillemotleft}%
  }%
}}

\begin{document}

\kiquote{Someone}{Said something}

\end{document}
```